# Sharp edges & white dots when using Depth in Compositing

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes

When I try to make fog with Depth in Cycles, noise appears on objects with transparent material & sharp edges are formed on the edges of objects even without Transparent. Every time I try to do aerial perspective, nothing coming out. Or I have to use Volumetric light, which takes too long rendering & needs a lot of samples to get rid of the fireflies. Either I'm trying to make fog in Photoshop. And for animations, these methods are generally not suitable. Fog adjusted with Depth looks very good, but the resulting artifacts spoil the whole picture. I tried to find the answer in internet, but all methods that were indicated there didn't work. Help me please please please, how to make fog correctly so that there are no sharp edges at the edges & white dots on Transparent?

[image]